# ntfsclone reports "Can't read sector at 470585344, lost data". How can I determine what file that is?

Tags: partition, ntfs, copy, ubuntu-10.10, rescue-disk

I used ntfsclone from ubuntu to copy a bad windows hard drive to a new one using:

```
sudo ntfsclone --rescue -f --overwrite /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
```

which produces the following:

```
WARNING: Can't read sector at 470585344, lost data.
```

There's only about 70 of these warnings.  How could I determine what real files were affected using these numbers?

Answer (score 1):

On the hunt for the opposite, file to sector address resolution if you will, I came across your question.  On a Windows box, using nfi.exe found in the Windows 2000 OEM toolkit: see http://forums.seagate.com/t5/Barracuda-XT-Barracuda-Barracuda/Tip-How-to-determine-which-file-occupies-a-particular-sector/td-p/35567